# Wildcard imports with `as` in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, import, module, export, node-modules

I am primarily a JavaScript developer, but with some recent exposure to Java, I rather enjoy how Java handles wildcard imports. Without using any `as` statements, the import takes all named imports and imports them directly into the current namespace/scope as variables/classes without any need for there to be one variable they are properties of.

Is this possible in JavaScript. For example, if I make this export:

#### Export Example

```js
export const a = 1;
export const b = 2;
export const c = 3;
export default const d = 4;
```

Then this would be true of related imports:

#### Wildcard Imports Example

```js
import * as Foo from "./file.js";

Foo.a // -> 1
Foo.b // -> 2
Foo.c // -> 3
Foo.d // -> 4
```

#### Default Import Example

```js
import Foo from "./file.js";

Foo // -> 4
```

#### Specific/Named Imports Example

```js
import { a, b } from "./file.js";

a // -> 1
b // -> 2
c // -> undefined
d // -> undefined
```

What I am looking for, which it appears Java supports, is the ability to do something like the current JavaScript wildcard import, but without the `as` statement, like the below example, where all named exports are imported as fully accessible variables within the current namespace/scope:

#### Wildcard Imports (without `as`) Example - DESIRED

```js
import * from "./file.js";

a // -> 1
b // -> 2
c // -> 3
d // -> 4
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly not.

I guess this is precisely not allowed by the ES6 spec. The [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#namespace_import) is quite clear on the matter; I quote:

> Note: JavaScript does not have wildcard imports like import * from "module-name", because of the high possibility of name conflicts.